# Make a HTTP request using SOCKS Proxy

Tags: go, socks

I'm trying to make a HTTP(s) request using a SOCKS5 Proxy. I have the following code, on executing it throws an error.

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

const (
    PROXY_ADDR = "socks5://175.101.15.35:84"
    URL        = "https://api.ipify.org?format=json"
)

func main() {
    url_i := url.URL{}
    url_proxy, _ := url_i.Parse(PROXY_ADDR)

    transport := http.Transport{}
    transport.Proxy = http.ProxyURL(url_proxy)                        // set proxy
    transport.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true} //set ssl
    client := &http.Client{Transport: &transport}
    // client.Transport = &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(url_proxy)}
    resp, err := client.Get(URL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    responseBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(responseBody))
}
```

**Error:**

```
Get "https://api.ipify.org?format=json": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 175.101.15.35:84: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x40 pc=0x82c909]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        C:/Users/XXX/main.go:29 +0x189
exit status 2
```

The Internet connectivity is fine and I've tried other alternatives for the above code but none of them seem to work.

Please help.

Comment: It says that it cannot connect to the given proxy address. This does not matter if the internet connectivity is fine by itself - if the proxy is not up, not reachable or if you given the wrong address of the proxy then the connection to the proxy will still fail.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message said, err is not nil from this line

```
resp, err := client.Get(URL)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return // need to exit here, because there is nothing in response
}
```

Please check the reachability of the endpoint 175.101.15.35:84